# PHP Overload class by other with the same name and namespace

Tags: php, reflection, overloading, clone, dynamic-loading

I have a directory tree where in different sub-directories I have a lot of classes with the same name. There is a strong intention to **not** edit these classes.

I'm looking for a way to load one class and after using it and destroying its instance load another with exactly the same name. Then use it, destroy its instance and repeat that process.

I thought some possible solutions:

1. Loading class with the same name that replaces previously loaded class (Overloads it)
2. Unloading a class before I load class with the same name but from different path
3. Creating a new class (dynamically created class body) under different name or by adding to it namespace. Creation process firstly reads source class body, its methods, properties and "copies" that to new class. Similar to clone on instances but done on class body level.
4. Read the first class, instantiate it, use its methods, destroy its instance. Then remove all methods inside first class and dynamically create inside it all methods that are read from the second class having the same name.
5. Read file content of a class and create temporary file with the class content you read but change class name or put unique namespace on top of it and finally load temporary file. (Least appealing approach to me)

For the 3rd I thought this could be useful: [Componere](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro.componere.php) or [Runkit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) or [Classkit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.classkit-import.php) but don't have any experience with them.

Do you have any other ideas or perhaps some solutions?
Did you use [componere](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro.componere.php) or [Runkit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) / [Classkit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.classkit-import.php) and can say they suit the job? maybe there are other options?

Perhaps there is a OOP design pattern that covers this issue but I'm not familiar with it.

Example code:

```
<?php

#------------------------------------
//path Foo/Bar.php

/* class is without a namespace or have the same
as Baz/Bar.php */
class Bar
{
    public function getName() : string
    {
        return 'Foo/Bar';
    }
}

#------------------------------------
//path Baz/Bar.php

/* class is without a namespace or have the same
as Foo/Bar.php */
class Bar
{
    public function getName() : string
    {
        return 'Baz/Bar';
    }
}

#------------------------------------
//path ./Execute.php

$paths = [
    'Foo/Bar.php',
    'Baz/Bar.php'
];

$results = [];
foreach ($paths as $path) {

    //how to create instance of class Bar in Foo/Bar.php and then in Baz/Bar.php
    //without PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class...
    $classDynamic = ...

    $results[] = $classDynamic->getName();
    unset($classDynamic);
}

var_export($results)

/**
 * prints
 * array('Foo/Bar', 'Baz/Bar')
 */
```

Comment: Is spawning a subprocess for every class you want to load in this way an option for you?

Comment: @thehennyy I didn't think about that, do you have any examples? what are downsides? Can this be done at PHP script level?

Comment: You probably need permission to start processes on your system and you have to know where the php executable is located. Starting another process should be as easy as `exec( 'php yourscripttoloadclasses.php')`. Also you have to select a way to get your data back (stdout, filesystem, db, ...).

Comment: @thehennyy this makes sense, I use php on Docker, and I'm able to run other containers including php container from within php inside the Docker so this approach should work. How would you make the spawned subprocess to include a particular class, pass the class path from parent process as a CLI argument to exec command?

Comment: Yeah just pass the information you need as command line arguments. You do not have to start another container, you can start the subprocess in the same container if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to unset a class once it has been defined and as they share the same namespace they will error out.
but you could get the effect you wanted as follows

```
class Bar
{
    $myname = "";
    function __construct($setname="")
    {
       $this->myname = $setname;
    }
    function getName()
    {
       return $myname;
    }
}

$paths = array('Foo/Bar','Baz/Bar');
$results = array();
foreach($paths as $p)
{
   $bit = new Bar($p);
   $results[] = $bit->getName();
}
var_export($results);
```

Comment: Thank you but this does not apply, You just pass a variable to the class that does not affect class name but only the value that is returned by its method.